# How to disable lockscreen in kubuntu 15.10?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, kde

How can I disable the lockscreen? I read this [How to disable sleep/screensaver Kubuntu 12.04 LTS and VLC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193930/how-to-disable-sleep-screensaver-kubuntu-12-04-lts-and-vlc) and can't help me because in my system with disabled suspend session again locks the screen and asks for password ...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

KDE System Settings > Desktop Behavior > Screen Locking.
Take the tick off from the 'Lock screen on resume'

[image]